# Deploying a multi-container docker application to Azure Container Service

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, azure-container-service

I have a multi-container docker application on Github which can be accessed [here](https://github.com/anznpatel/docker-ethercis). I want to deploy this docker application on Azure using the DC/OS orchestration with the help of the ACS cluster (I am able to run the application locally).

I followed this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-setup-ci-cd guide on the azure docs and managed to deploy a sample application. I am not able to send a request to the server at that port. I tried to change the port of the docker-compose.yml file so that I can map port 5000 on the outside, to 8080 on the inside but it does not seem to work.

*Code can be accessed on Github*

The docker-compose.yml currently looks like this

```
services:
app:
  build: ./application
  image: ethercis-app

ports:
  - "5000:8080"
depends_on:
  - postgres

postgres:
  build: ./postgres
  image: ethercis-db
```

Comment: Does it work locally? The indention of `docker-compose.yml` is wrong.

Comment: [link](https://github.com/anznpatel/docker-ethercis/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) original docker-compose file, indentation is incorrect on stack overflow only

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: based on the additional information you provide in the comment below:

In your LB Rule you are using a probe on port 80 but your container is exposing port 5000. 
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-enable-public-access

Original response:
ACS uses port 8080 for Marathon on the masters, not the agents. Your workloads run on the agents so there should be no problem in the port mapping. What are the symptoms that make you say there is a port clash?

Comment: I have attached some [screenshots](http://imgur.com/a/iB4J4) for you, in my original docker-compose file, I define the ports as "5000:8080". This does not seem to be working, I cannot make any queries to that port and its either I get a 'tcp connection refused' error or page keeps loading forever

Comment: Thanks for noting that, I have added the probe on port 5000 and linked it to the LB Rule, now the issue is that the connection times out. Within DCOS, the endpoints of the deployed service keep changing every time I click on them.